# Convert stored procedure to view in SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

In this stored procedure we have a temp table and cursors and we are updating a temp table. How can we convert this to a view? Because views not consider temp table.

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
GO

EXECUTE DDLDropProcedure 'spu_Report_Audit_Fees'
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE spu_Report_Audit_Fees
    @Source_id int
AS
    DECLARE @transdetail_id INT
    DECLARE @Client_premium NUMERIC(19, 3)
    DECLARE @Client_code VARCHAR(10)
    DECLARE @Client_name VARCHAR(100)
    DECLARE @Fees_code VARCHAR(10)
    DECLARE @Fees_name VARCHAR(30)
    DECLARE @Fees_amount NUMERIC(19, 3)
    DECLARE @VAT_code VARCHAR(10)
    DECLARE @VAT_amount NUMERIC(19, 3)
    DECLARE @sub_branch_id INT

-- get default sub-branch for supplied source_id
EXEC spu_sub_branch_default @source_id, @sub_branch_id OUTPUT

SELECT DISTINCT
    TD.transdetail_id,
    TD.accounting_date,
    TD.insurance_ref,
    TD.comment,
    A.short_code,
    D.Document_ref,
    DT.description document_type,
    Client_premium = CONVERT(numeric(19, 3), 0),
    A.short_code Client_code,
    A.account_name Client_name,
    Fees_code = A.short_code,
    Fees_name = A.account_name,
    Fees_amount = CONVERT(numeric(19, 3), 0),
    VAT_code = A.short_code,
    VAT_amount = CONVERT(numeric(19, 3), 0),
    D.document_date
INTO 
    #TempTable
FROM 
    TransDetail TD,
    Period P, -- Just an observation, this table is not restricted in any way.
              -- If this procedure is broken it is most likely here.
    Document D,
    DocumentType DT,
    Account A
WHERE 
    TD.document_id = D.document_id
    AND D.documenttype_id = DT.documenttype_id
    AND TD.account_id = A.account_id
    AND D.documenttype_id = 30
    AND A.sub_branch_id = @sub_branch_id
ORDER BY 3

DECLARE c_Cursor CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR
    SELECT transdetail_id FROM #TempTable

OPEN c_Cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM c_Cursor INTO @transdetail_id

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN
    /* Get the correct value for Client_premium */
    SELECT @Client_premium = TD.amount
                FROM TransDetail TD,
                Account A, Ledger L,
                Document D
                WHERE D.document_id = TD.document_id
                AND TD.Account_id = A.Account_id
                AND A.Ledger_id IN (SELECT ledger_id FROM ledger WHERE ledger_short_name = 'SA') --PSL 16/06/2003 Iss4707 Remove Hard coded ledger_id
                AND TD.transdetail_id = @transdetail_id

    /* Get the correct value for Client_code & Fees_code*/
    SELECT @Client_code = A.short_code,
            @Client_name = A.account_name
    FROM TransDetail TD,
            TransDetail TD2,
            Account A,
            Ledger L,
            Document D
    WHERE D.document_id = TD.document_id
    AND TD.document_id = TD2.document_id
    AND TD.Account_id = A.Account_id
    AND A.Ledger_id IN (SELECT ledger_id FROM ledger WHERE ledger_short_name = 'SA') --PSL 16/06/2003 Iss4707 Remove Hard coded ledger_id
    AND TD2.transdetail_id = @transdetail_id
    AND A.sub_branch_id = @sub_branch_id

    /* Get the correct value for Fees_amount */
    SELECT @Fees_code = A.short_code,
            @Fees_name = A.account_name,
            @Fees_amount = TD.amount
    FROM TransDetail TD,
            TransDetail TD2,
            Account A,
            Ledger L,
            Document D
    WHERE D.document_id = TD.document_id
    AND TD.document_id = TD2.document_id
    AND TD.Account_id = A.Account_id
    AND A.Ledger_id IN (SELECT ledger_id FROM ledger WHERE ledger_short_name = 'FE') --PSL 16/06/2003 Iss4707 Remove Hard coded ledger_id
    AND TD2.transdetail_id = @transdetail_id
    AND A.sub_branch_id = @sub_branch_id

    /* Get the correct value for VAT_code & amount */
    SELECT @VAT_code = A.short_code,
            @VAT_amount = TD.amount
    FROM TransDetail TD,
            TransDetail TD2,
            Account A,
            Ledger L,
            Document D
    WHERE D.document_id = TD.document_id
    AND TD.document_id = TD2.document_id
    AND TD.Account_id = A.Account_id
    AND A.Ledger_id IN (SELECT ledger_id FROM ledger WHERE ledger_short_name = 'NO') --PSL 16/06/2003 Iss4707 Remove Hard coded ledger_id
    AND TD2.transdetail_id = @transdetail_id
    AND A.sub_branch_id = @sub_branch_id

    /* Update the temporary table */
    UPDATE #TempTable
    SET Client_premium = ISNULL(@Client_premium, 0.0),
        Client_code = ISNULL(@Client_code, ''),
        Client_name = ISNULL(@Client_name, ''),
        Fees_code = ISNULL(@Fees_code, ''),
        Fees_name = ISNULL(@Fees_name, ''),
        Fees_amount = ISNULL(@Fees_amount, 0.0),
        VAT_code = ISNULL(@VAT_code, ''),
        VAT_amount = ISNULL(@VAT_amount, 0.0)
    WHERE transdetail_id = @transdetail_id

    /* Move to the next row */
    FETCH NEXT FROM c_Cursor INTO @transdetail_id
END

/* Clear up our cursor */
CLOSE c_Cursor
DEALLOCATE c_Cursor

/* Select everything now */

SELECT * FROM #TempTable

DELETE #TempTable

DROP TABLE #TempTable
GO
```

Comment: can you edit your question and remove extra blank lines in the codes ?

Comment: Why do you want to do the "conversion" ? Is it due to performance ?

Comment: I think the short answer is that you can't use cursors inside views. You would have to find a way to rewrite this stored procedure as a single `select` statement, perhaps using a [`Common Table Expression`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql) to wrap up some of the functionality, and use that to make your view. Be aware that CTEs, especially recursive CTEs, can have dire impacts on performance if not written very carefully.

Comment: From a quick look at your code (re-formatting to make it readable - please do this yourself in future) I suspect its highly unlikely you will ever be able to convert that into a view. And even if it was possible I would be surprised if anyone here would invest the time required to do so. Sorry.

Comment: Again - why do you think you need to convert it? views don't take parameters, can't capture results from sp's, can't use variables. You can't convert it so I suggest you explain why you think you need to?

Comment: Because they want to use as a  table with where condition...where row data already calculated.

Comment: Without some serious redesign of the existing codebase (and probably schema too), this task is impossible. Given the many issues with the code currently present, your development group needs to have a serious talk about improved coding practices. You and "they" need to talk about setting realistic goals.

Comment: "where row data already calculated".  No- a view does not pre-calculate data.  And even if you were able to re-write that using a view- the performance would be abysmal, taking at least several times longer to execute than the stored procedure.

Comment: Time to start using ANSI-92 style joins instead of these antiquated ANSI-89 joins. They have been around now for more than 25 years. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins

Comment: Output the results of the SP into a temp table and then apply the `where` clause to the temp table.

Comment: @DaleBurrell i am talking about convert it to view. But view doesn't support temp table.

Comment: You can't convert it to a view, I'm offering alternative suggestions.